# Why does Hazelcast IMap.putTransient fire the EntryAddedListener?

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Using version 3.6.1, why do we have different behavior for put and putTransient with respect to map listeners (.putTransient fires added, and .put fires updated)?

```
public void testNoDelta() {
    String str = "world";
    String key = "hello";
    map.putTransient(key, str, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    map.putTransient(key, str, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    map.putTransient(key, str, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    map.putTransient(key, str, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    map.put(key, str);
    map.put(key, str);
    map.put(key, str);
    map.put(key, str);
}
```

Comment: Do you get `EVICTED`/`EXPIRED` events too ?

Comment: I don't see any evicted or expired events.

Comment: That's fine, it's just a way to help with diagnosis, but you'd need to be listening for these events too in order to get them. The behaviour these would help validate is whether the entry is already there when you do the `put` ; if you've seen a `EVICTED` then it has been removed and if you've not seen an `EVICTED` yet (but get them in general) then most likely the entry is there. If you know whether the entry is there or not, you can know whether to expect an `UPDATED` or `ADDED` event respectively.

Comment: And then, once you have a way to cross-check what behaviour you get for the object presense/absence, you can see if it's the same as the issue that @vassilis-bekiaris mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit [this issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10077) which is fixed in Hazelcast 3.8.1 by https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/10082.

Comment: I've reopened https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10077. ADDED and UPDATED events look correct for the code sample from @hklf but not expiry events.